# WRAP_CONTENT fills parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a couple of activities with controls that I want to wrap content, but for some reason, they end up filling the parent. Inspecting them with the hierarchy viewer shows them with WRAP_CONTENT set, but the bounding box of the view clearly taking up the rest of the space on the screen.

[image]

The view is outlined above, and as you can see, layout_width is WRAP_CONTENT, but it fills the screen. And yes, I've checked and its child LinearLayout does not fill the width--it ends where its parent is supposed to.

EDIT: The image was really just to show how exactly the view ends up laid out. Here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:id="@+id/cart_table">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/footer">
        <View android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/h2"
                  android:gravity="right"
                  android:id="@+id/grand_total" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<com.eftours.TDLinkv2.Payment.Controls.PaymentForm
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cart_table"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/payment_form" />
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/small_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/payment_form"
        android:id="@+id/checkout_button"
        android:text="Checkout" />
```

Comment: post your xml, it's not clear in your image.

Comment: Maybe this is just Hierarchy Viewer, but it's usually `wrap_content`, not `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Comment: wrap_content in the XML, WRAP_CONTENT in code